# 2-Sphere is connected

Tags: general-topology

I am supposed to show, that if I have a continuous function $F:S^2→ (\mathbb{R}, | · |)$, with $S^2$ being the 2-Sphere in $\mathbb{R^3}$, that there is a point  where $F(x)=F(-x)$. Now I know how to do a majority of the proof. One has to show that $S^2$ is connected, therefore the image of $G(x):=F(x)-F(-x)$ is connected and because in $\mathbb{R}$ a set is connected iff it is an interval, and because $G(-x)=-G(x)$ we know that the image of $G(x)$ has to contain $0$, and therefor the function $F(x)$ has a zero point. What I am struggling with however is showing that $S^2$ is connected. I do not have any idea how to show that, at the moment i am trying to show that it is path connected, but I am having trouble defining a function that alloqws me to prove this. Any ideas?

Edit: We have not gone into particularly much depth on the topic, as I am only a second semester math student so I would be happy if someone could give a simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: It is easy to show it is path connected - just join two points by a great circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know that union of connected sets with a point in common is connected? If so, then the sphere is the union of two disks along their boundary, and disks are connected as you may well know.

Another simple solution is parametrizing the sphere, which takes the closed square surjectively in the sphere. Since continuous maps take connected sets to connected sets, the result follows.

---

If you know the concept of path-connectedness, you can join two points in a sphere in the following way (and note this generalizes to $S^n$) :

For any two non-antipodal points $x,y$, join them by a line in $x+t(y-x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n%$ and consider the path
$$\frac{1}{\Vert x+t(y-x)\Vert}(x+t(y-x)).$$
Therefore, we can connect any two non-antipodal points on the sphere. If they are antipodal points, take any other $z$ and concatenate the paths.

Exercise: Why is it important that $x,y$ are not antipodal points?

Comment: Interesting to see if he goes for this. I would have thought it was no harder to prove properties directly for $S^2$ than for the disk.

Comment: @almagest The disk being connected is immediate from the fact that the cartesian product of connected sets is connected, and this does not use the concept of path connectedness, which OP may not be familiar with.

Even if OP is familiar with path connectedness, it is immediate that the disk is path connected, whereas some (minor) ammount of calculation is needed to show that every two points on a sphere can be joined by a great circle. I'll give an argument of path-connectedness which do not use great circles directly though.

Comment: "may not be familiar with" except that he explicitly asks for help in proving that it is path connected.

Comment: @almagest You are right. I didn't read that, my bad.

Comment: +1 for your previous comment, which makes a point I had failed to think of! :(

Comment: Thank you for the help! We did not go over the fact that disks are connected but proving that should be doable.

Comment: And they cant be antipods because for t=0.5 we would be dividing by zero ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that any two points on the sphere lie on some great circle. Once you figure out the equation of the great circle, then choosing any one of the arcs gives you a path between those two points.

Another method would be showing that $S^2$ is the continuous image of a connected set in $\mathbb{R^2}$. But the first method is much natural I think.

Comment: How would one go about defining the great circle that the two points lie on? I have never done that in three dimensional space

Comment: @lelman You don't need that. See my answer.